# Topic particle after "expression of time"

Tags: grammar, particle-は

I am reading chapter 4 from the JLPT N5 book, where I found the following sentence:

> 昨日勉強しましたか。

After 昨日, why wasn't there a topic particle? Is "昨日は勉強しましたか。" an incorrect sentence?

Answer (score 6):

Marking it with は is certainly not wrong, and would in fact be natural. It doesn't change the meaning, but if the は is stressed, it will contrast yesterday to all other days, and will thus put stress on the time:

> 昨日勉強しましたか - Did you study yesterday? (Plain question)
>   昨日**は**勉強しましたか - Did you study **yesterday**? (As opposed to any other day)

However, if the は is not stressed, then は is a normal topic marker and it is still a plain question:

> 昨日は勉強しましたか - Did you study yesterday? (Plain question, は unstressed)

(Thanks to naruto for pointing this out in the comments.)

Comment: I would probably say 「昨日は勉強しましたか」 when I want to plainly ask "Did you study yesterday?" as opposed to nothing.

Comment: @naruto So, it doesn't emphasize the time after all?

Comment: I think it depends on the pronunciation; when は is stressed, it would be the contrastive-wa, but otherwise it would be the usual topic marker. Perhaps OP just didn't know 昨日 can act as an adverb by itself?

Comment: Huh, I was not aware of that distinction. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I wonder why nobody say anything about 晩強...

Comment: @broccoliforest あっごめん、コメントに気づかないで編集してしまった・・

Comment: Well, you can tell which ones I copied and pasted from the OP's question. lol